# Lebesgue measure, do we have $m(x + A) = m(A)$, $m(cA) = |c|m(A)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $m$ is Lebesgue measure. Define $x + A = \{x + y : y \in A\}$ and $cA = \{cy : y \in A\}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c$ a real number. Let $A$ be a Lebesgue measurable set. I have two questions.

1. Does $m(x + A) = m(A)$?
2. Does $m(cA) = |c|m(A)$?

Comment: Question 1 has already been asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1707922/how-to-prove-that-lebesgue-measure-is-translation-invariant)

Comment: Question 2 is a special case of [this question about $\mathbb{R}^n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1756545/linearity-of-lebesgue-measure)

Comment: Unfortunately neither question is really answered :/

Answer (score 1):

The lebegue measure  is invariant by translations so the answer is yes it is.
Just writing the definition also the second follow.